# IndexOutOfRangeException C#

Tags: c#, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception

My goal is to make a triple for loop to multiply matrix X matrix, i get in input the matrix and i have to get matrix^2.

I get the error "IndexOutOfRangeException" - index was outside the bounds of the array when i debug the following code:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < nodeList.Count+1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < nodeList.Count+1; j++)
                {
                    result[i, j] = "0";

                    for (int k = 1; k < nodeList.Count+1; i++)
                    {

                        if ((matrix[i, k] != null) && (matrix[k, j] != null))
                        {
                            n1 = Convert.ToInt32(matrix[i, k]);
                            n2 = Convert.ToInt32(matrix[k, j]);
                            n3 = Convert.ToInt32(result[i, j]);

                            total = n3 + n1 * n2;
                            _total = total.ToString();

                            result[i, j] = _total;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

where the variables are:
1. matrix that is type String[,] and the dimensions are (nodelist+1,nodelist+1)
2.result that is is the same type and dimension of the matrix, where i want to put the resultant matrix
3.nodelist is the array of the names of the nodes that i have in the diagram
4. n1,n2,n3 are int, I put in them the convert int from the matrix
5.total is the result of the operation for the multiplication
6._total convert total int in total string for the result matrix

So i set the right dimensions for every array and matrix but i get constantly the same error. I don't get it why. Can please someone help to notice the error, because i don't see it.

Comment: Before posting here, I'm SURE you ran this in a debugger, and stepped through until you got the exception, and examined your variables.  Right?  Really, right?

Answer (score 5):

In the `k` loop, you are incrementing `i`.

Comment: i spent the whole afternooon on this!!! i couldn't get the error, omg! i can believe it! thank you a lot i needed a pair of fresh eyes :D thank you =****

Comment: Had you used a debugger and stepped through your code, you would have found the answer immediately.  Debugger usage is NOT OPTIONAL.

Comment: @abelenky yes i had, but i couldn't noticed why the k didn't increment but stopped.

Comment: I see nothing in your original post that indicates "I watched it in a debugger, and `k` didn't increment when I thought it should".

Answer (score 3):

for (int k = 1; k < nodeList.Count+1; i++) <-- you are incrementing i, it should be incrementing k.

like this:

for (int k = 1; k < nodeList.Count+1; k++)

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are 0-based in C# -- the first element is at position 0 instead of position 1.

```
for (int i = 1; i < nodeList.Count+1; i++)
```

... should be ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
```

You also have what appears to be a copy-paste error for the k-loop.

```
for (int k = 1; k < nodeList.Count+1; i++)  // should be k++?
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to use a for loop with an array is to use

`for(int x= 0; x < arry.count ;x++)`

using 1 and +1 as the conditional will assure that you get an index out of rage as c# arrays are indexed by 0

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you are incrementing by i in the K loop.

Also you will be getting the out of bounds error every time you try to access an matrix on the last iteration of the loops.  Either you need to go from 0 to Count in your loops or you need to put a -1 in all of your matrix operations. ex:

```
results[i-1, j-1] = _total;
```

The matrix indexes start at 0.